# Form submit error when using CKEditor plugin for web2py

Tags: forms, web2py

I am using the CKEditor plugin for web2py. The problem I have is that on the form, when someone clicks a dropdown value, the form is submitted using javascript, the id in the request.vars is used to generate new form values(form.vars.body), which works fine until the code reaches form.accepts(req..., sess..). For some reason the widget value(form.vars.body) is changed to the original value before the submit(other form.vars fields change and work fine). My question is does form.accepts(req.., ses..) change or call anything in the widget code again to revert that particular field to its original value.

`query1 = db.contents.event_instance_id==event_instance_id

query2 = db.contents.section==section_id`

contents = db(query1 & query2).select(db.contents.id, db.contents.title,db.contents.body).first()

```
record=contents.id
fields = ['id','section', 'title', 'body']

# get form
# this returns the correct form.xml with the right content for db.contents.body
form = SQLFORM(db.contents, record, fields=fields, submit_button=T('Save Content'))

if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
    response.flash = T("Contents saved")
elif form.errors:
    response.flash = T("Error saving content")

# but after form.accepts the form.xml is different, form.vars.body is different, 
# which is then passed to the view with the wrong content for the field with widget
return dict(form=form, title=title, event_instance_id=event_instance_id)
```

## in the model

db.define_table('contents',
    Field('event_instance_id', 'reference event_instance', label='Event Instance'),
    Field('section', 'reference sections'),
    Field('title', length=255, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('body', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), widget=ckeditor.widget)
)

In the view its just `{{=form}}`

Comment: Can you show the code? What do you mean by "the original value before the submit"? Note, `form.accepts()` reads the values submitted via `request.post_vars`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the form.xml"? Can you point to the code for the ckeditor plugin? Is the correct text being saved in the db?

Comment: I mean the form object converted html is correct before going through the form.accepts method. After that it changes to some html values, in this case the widget fields html. All I want to know is does form.accepts do anything in regards to form widgets field, does it call any of its functions again with the default value.